# Why am I getting this error message when I try to open Python? "Unexpected error ParseError:Invalid line at line "1"."

Tags: python, windows, enthought, parse-error, canopy

How can I fix this. Python is currently unaccessible for me because of this error. Everytime that I click on my python icon to begin programming, the error message  pops up, and it will not allow me to run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known error, fixed in upcoming Canopy 1.2. Sorry!

Meantime, manual fix:

Delete preferences.ini file (which is corrupted). This file is located at:

Windows:

```
%APPDATA%\Enthought\Canopy
```

OSX or Linux:

```
~/.canopy
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to an Enthought Knowledge Base article re-iterating Jonathan March's solution:

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23097479-Restarting-Canopy-after-Unexpected-error-ParseError